# Airflow Upstart Goes Straight to Stop/Waiting

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-14.04, airflow, upstart

I am trying to have the Airflow scheduler & webserver running in the background on the ubuntu EC2 instance. Whenever I start the upstart job, the airflow-webserver job goes straight to stop/waiting. Here is the .conf file that I have saved in /etc/init. (I used anaconda to install airflow)

```
description "Airflow webserver daemon"

start on started networking
stop on (deconfiguring-networking or runlevel [016])

respawn
respawn limit 5 30

setuid unbuntu
setgid unbuntu

env AIRFLOW_CONFIG=/home/ubuntu/airflow/airflow.cfg
env AIRFLOW_HOME=/home/ubuntu/airflow/
export AIRFLOW_CONFIG
export AIRFLOW_HOME

exec /home/ubuntu/anaconda3/bin/airflow webserver
```

When I check the logs, this is what I am seeing:

```
starting airflow-webserver...
/home/airflow/airflow/
/home/airflow/airflow/airflow.cfg
[2018-07-23 19:44:29,341] {__init__.py:45} INFO - Using executor SequentialExecutor
  ____________       _____________
 ____    |__( )_________  __/__  /________      __
____  /| |_  /__  ___/_  /_ __  /_  __ \_ | /| / /
___  ___ |  / _  /   _  __/ _  / / /_/ /_ |/ |/ /
 _/_/  |_/_/  /_/    /_/    /_/  \____/____/|__/

[2018-07-23 19:44:29,883] {models.py:189} INFO - Filling up the DagBag from /home/ubuntu/airflow/dags
Running the Gunicorn Server with:
Workers: 4 sync
Host: 0.0.0.0:8080
Timeout: 120
Logfiles: - -
=================================================================
```

But then nothing after that.

Answer (score 1):

You set uid and gid to "unbuntu" instead of "ubuntu".

It appears that it is trying to run from the user "ubuntu" based on /home/ubuntu/ as shown in the log message.